# Will default constructor still be created if I explicitly define a constructor with arguments?

Tags: c++, constructor, default

Will default constructor still be created if I explicitly define a constructor **with** arguments but no default constructor?

Thank you!

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you have to explicitly provide the default constructor in that case.

Although you can (from C++11 onwards), for a class `Foo`, use the syntax

`Foo() = default;`

within the class declaration which *reintroduces* the compiler-generated default constructor. (Note you need to put this in the `public` section for exact equivalence).

Alternatively, if you provide default arguments to all the constructor parameters, then it *becomes* the default constructor.

Answer (score 4):

No, it won't, that's the point when you want class users to explicitly provide arguments.

However, if you use default values for your parameters, it becomes the default constructor

```
class Foo
{
     Foo(bool flag=false);  // not a default constructor, but acts the same
};
```

Comment: Actually it does become the default constructor.

Comment: It actually is a default constructor. I quote the standard from memory (so I might be a little off): a default constructor is a constructor that can be called without any parameters.

Comment: right. Edited (also added `bool` type, too much python those days :))

Comment: What about the case in which multiple constructors with are defined, all of which are given default argument values? Is that a semantic error?

Answer (score 0):

No. If you define a constructor, only the constructors that you define are present. If you want to keep the default constructor, you have to redefine it.

```
class MyClass
{
   MyClass(){};
.
.
.
};
```

Comment: Consider `= default` notation instead.

Comment: That is also an option. But only available since C++11.

Comment: I wish people would start asume the latest standard by default. So instead of "This is what you can do. Oh and by the way since c++11 you can also do this" to say "This is what you can do. Before c++11 you had to do this instead"

Comment: @bolov agreed but then why do we have to type `-std=c++11` each time? It should be by default too (I'm new at C++ 11 but I love it and I'm a quick learner)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the default for `gcc` is `gnu++14` which is a GNU dialect of -std=c++14. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html

Comment: @bolov unfortunately, there is many, a lot, legacy systems based on c++98. But I totally agree. Another issue, programmers a so used to the old c++ that they don't even bother looking what's new in the newest standard...